# Extjs 4.2.1 Ext.Msg.show rtl not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4, right-to-left

In my index.html Im using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ext-all-rtl.js></script>
```

Im trying to show msgbox using the attribute **rtl:true** likewise:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    rtl: true,
    title: "...",
    msg: "...",
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.Error,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

When the message shown the rtl isn't working and it shows the component ltr instead.

The other components such as windows, panels etc are working fine with the rtl attribute.

Is there something else needed for the MessageBox in order to use the rtl ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, probably I wasn't doing it right.

I passed the **rtl:true** parameter to the method **show** of the message box instead of defining the message box itself as rtl.

The answer for me was to create new message box supporting the rtl alignment likewise:

```
var message = Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox', {rtl: true});
```

And then I can just use it like this:

```
message.show({
    title: "...",
    msg: "...",
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.Error,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "rtl:true" config is inherited throughout the component hierarchy, you should be able to just add "rtl: true" to the top-level component in the hierarchy (usually the viewport). This eliminates any need to set "direction:rtl" yourself, since components in an rtl hierarchy will have the "x-rtl" class added to their element(s).

You also need to make sure you are using the rtl stylesheet, as Ext JS components require quite a bit of special styling to work correctly in rtl mode. For example, for the classic theme this would be: ext-theme-classic-all-rtl.css

If you're still stuck, have a look at this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/rtl/rtl.html?theme=classic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I pointed out, my other components such as windows, panels etc are aligned from right to left without any problem. My only problem is with the message box.